# Access element before page is fully loaded in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loading

Some websites tend to keep loading even after all the elements in the page are loaded. This is usually not a problem for humans but selenium tends to wait until the page fully finishes loading even when it could already interact with the given element.
Is there a way to bypass this or maybe stop loading when a certain element is detected? I couldnt figure it out from other posts. Thanks

Comment: You mean driver.set_page_load_timeout(5) or etc? Or wait till the webdriver wait picks up the presence of an element then execute a window.stop in a driver.execute().

Comment: Wait till element is loaded and then stop loading so the second option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503576/selenium-python-how-to-stop-page-loading-when-certain-element-gets-loaded has an example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a load strategy. Default is `normal`, other options are `eager` and `none`

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# Navigate to url
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```