# Selenium page load take more than expected timeout

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

In my case, I don't want to wait more than 15 seconds after calling the method `driver.get()`. I have the following code:

```
...
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
try:
    driver.get(url) 
except TimeoutException as e:
    pass

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = input_driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.dismiss()
except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
    pass
```

But it still takes in some cases (not sure when) more than 5 minutes. What am I doing false?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium + Python: How to stop page loading when certain element gets loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503576/selenium-python-how-to-stop-page-loading-when-certain-element-gets-loaded)

Comment: Yeah... so change the time to 15 seconds!!

Answer (score 1):

The page keeps loading for some time, you probably want to set the `pageLoadStrategy` capability to `none` and then stop the loading when the element you need is there, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504132/16025692) answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Change the value to 15 and the condition to wait until to the one that fits your needs and you're good!

Comment: After the website has loaded whatever you need from it, that script will stop it from loading anything else you don't need.

Comment: If the page times out it will go to the catch block in your code and you can handle that there. The window close code only stops the page from loading further from what you need, you don't have to include it if you don't want to.